# Convert hive function(space, split) to Redshift syntax to generate a date series

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift, hiveql, unix-timestamp, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a segment of code written in Hiveql that generates 3 columns, a index, a date, and a range of dates:

```
drop table if exists date_list;
create temporary table date_list as
with seq as(
select date_add('2020-02-27',s.i) as dt
from(
select posexplode(split(space(datediff('2020-12-01','2020-02-27')),' ')) as (i,x)
)s
)
select *,
row_number() over() index_n,
int(REGEXP_REPLACE(substring(dt,6,10),'\\-','')) as date_index

from seq;
```

Output:

[image]

.
.
.

[image]

Now, I need to convert to Redshift syntax due to a database migration, functions such as space, split do not exist in Redshift. How do I convert the code to be able to run in Redshift?

Running the same code generates such error:

```
[Code: 500310, SQL State: 42601]  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ")" 
Position: 169;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is done with a recursive cte.  I answered a similar question a bit ago.

[trying to create a date table in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883072/trying-to-create-a-date-table-in-redshift/69901710#69901710)

Generating the other columns from the list of dates is straight forward.