# Redshift, error in create a table with generated series

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift, hiveql, amazon-redshift-spectrum, generate-series

I'm trying to save a generated date series in a temporary table on redshit:

```
drop table if exists date_list;
create temporary table date_list as
with seq as(
select date '2020-02-27' + i as dt
from generate_series(1, (date '2020-12-01' - date '2020-02-27')) i
)
select * from seq;
```

But received the following error:

```
[Code: 500310, SQL State: 0A000]  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

I do not what part of the code caused this error since the syntax should be right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generate_series() is a leader-node-only function and its results cannot be used on the compute nodes.  The way to do this is with a recursive cte.  See:

[trying to create a date table in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883072/trying-to-create-a-date-table-in-redshift/69901710#69901710)